# How to pass the value of build number format as a parameter to powershell script in TFS 2010

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have embedded a powershell script in my build process template, and I wish to pass the build number format to it as a parameter.

The build number format is a VBScript expression:

```
$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)_$(Rev:.r)
```

The arguments I am passing to the powershell script have the following expression:

```
String.Format(" ""& '{0}' '{1}' "" ", MyScriptFileName, BuildNumberFormat.ToString())
```

But at runtime, I see that the value is the literal

```
$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)_$(Rev:.r)
```

I need it in a form like 'DEV_20140520.2'

I am using TFS 2010. Any ideas how to get it in the right format?

Comment: Have you managed to sort this out? i need help with this please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I sorted it out myself, instead of `BuildNumberFormat.ToString()`, I used the property `BuildDetail.BuildNumber`